# c# mysql incrementing null error

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, exception

I am updating a mysql database and even tho the value is set at 0,I get a strange error.

I try to run this:

```
MySqlCommand update = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE email_batch SET numberOfSendAttempts = numberOfSendAttempts + 1 AND sentOn = @sentOn WHERE outputFolder = @outputFolder", conn);
update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sentOn", DateTime.Now);
update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@outputFolder", outputFolder);
update.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

but I get this error

```
Exception has occurred: CLR/MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException
An unhandled exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll: 'Column 'numberOfSendAttempts' cannot be null'
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int64& insertedId)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at emailBatchReader.emailBatchReader.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\tpaolini\Desktop\sendEmailBatch\emailBatchReader.cs:line 332
```

which I know happens because I set the value to not null, but it should be setting it to increment up 1. I checked my mysql syntax and that seems to be correct and I checked it without the increment statement and it works. What about my statement is trying to make that value null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [comma's](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html) to separate fields to set, not `AND`

```
UPDATE email_batch
SET numberOfSendAttempts = numberOfSendAttempts + 1, sentOn = @sentOn
WHERE outputFolder = @outputFolder
```